# How to make a website look like a Windows Office application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, coldfusion

I have a simple question which my Google searches were unable to find a decent answer to. I completely understand how to design websites with HTML, CSS and ColdFusion, but they always tend to look like a regular website with common navigation bar across the top, a sidebar, and then some main content.

However I have also seen some software being used which looks exactly like a Windows Office application, even though it is being delivered through a browser. The ones I have seen are used in HR and CRM applications which are hosted in the cloud and accessed by companies through the internet. They look and feel exactly like Microsoft Outlook with the same rich functionality but are actually a website.

So my questions is how do you go about making a site look like a Windows application? Where do you get all the nice icons, fonts, colour schemes, Javascript to put together a Windows 'theme'? Do you have to do everything from scratch yourself?

Comment: Websites can look like anything you want to, but you need to use your own icons, fonts and colour schemes. Copying Microsofts will break Copyright stuff

Comment: Are you sure? If you use a Windows SDK then I thought you would get access to Windows themes.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Asking on [**Webmasters**](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [**User Experience**](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) might get you what you want.

Comment: My apologies I will ask elsewhere. But I think Andrey has given me a good suggestion.

Comment: ExtJS is just one of many JS widget toolkits - they provide a consistent pre-set look, but don't necessarily make things look/act like Windows. See the GUI/widget section here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries

Comment: If you considering ExtJS you should try Ample SDK, if you are looking for a JavaScript library that would simplify coding against DOM, take jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such purposes you can use extjs javascript library

Comment: very good, it does look similar to what I was looking for.

Comment: http://dhtmlx.com/ is also a good library / api.